# Float class toString method

Tags: java

Why toString() method present in any type wrappers class (also subclass of Number class) is static while passing number as parameter but not when invoking on an object?
Like in Float class:-
When passing number

```
static String toString(float num)
```

When invoking on Object:-

```
String toString( )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are two different methods.

1.the static method

```
public static String toString(float f)
```

is a static method, so is associated to the class,  not to instances. 
You don't need an instance to call it.
So a static method is called statically by doing for example `Integer.toString(f)`

2.the instance method

```
public String toString()
```

is an instance method, so is associated to instances of the class and not to the class itself.
You must have a instance to call it.

---

To answer to your question, suppose we would like to be able to have an instance method to do what the static `toString(myLong)` method does. 
In this way, we could do it : `myLong.toString(myLong)`

To achieve it, the original static method should have been provided in two flavors : one with the static modifier and another without the static modifier (instance method) while the one with the instance method will never use the state of its instance to do the `toString()`. 
So, why should we create a instance method for that ?